# How do I take this from the console to a controller and view

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm learning Ruby on Rails (my first MVC) and have successfully setup a many-to-many relationship between "Agents" and "Zipcodes." What I'm trying to do currently is to get the associated agent based on the zip code entered by the user. I'm able to so successfully in the console, but am having a difficult time translating it to a controller and view.

What I do in the console:

```
zip = Zipcode.find_by_zip(gets.chomp)
=> 92562
zip.agents
```

The hangup I'm having is how to translate this into an action that I can access from a view with a form.

I've started by defining the action (agents#find), but am stumped as to whether this is correct and what comes after it.

```
def find
  @user_zip = Zipcode.find_by_zip(params[:zip])
end
```

Hopefully someone awesome in here can point a n00b in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When just starting with rails, I'd suggest avoiding custom actions like `#find` as much as possible, and instead sticking to [the "Big 7" RESTful routes](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions). Rails is really smooth when you work with it and do what it expects.

It sounds like maybe you're trying to identify a given zipcode, and then list all the agents associated with it. That sounds like a `#show` on `Zipcode`.

**config/routes.rb**

```
resources :zipcodes
```

**app/controllers/zipcodes_controller.rb**

```
ZipcodesController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @zipcode = Zipcode.find_by_zip(params[:id])
  end
end
```

**app/views/zipcodes/show.html.erb**

```
<div>
  <p>This zipcode has the following agents:</p>
  <ul>
    <%= @zipcode.agents.each do |agent| %>
      <li>Agent #<%= agent.id %></li>
    <% end %>
  </ul>
</div>
```

You can see this page by browsing to `/zipcodes/[zip]`.

Comment: Marking this answer correct for getting me 95% there. Wasn't exactly what I needed, but it helped me rethink the way I was doing things. It got me to flip things around a bit! Thanks for everyone's input!

Answer (score 0):

Just put `@user_zip = Zipcode.find_by_zip(params[:zip])` in the controller instead of the model.

In the view you will be able to call `@user_zip`.

Comment: Got that. Now I just need to figure out how to run the `zip.agents` part based on the `@user_zip.` Would that be achieved through something like: `@user_zip.agents`? I'm a little confused on how to tell rails to do something with the user's input. Moving from design to RoR is really stretching my brain.

Comment: @Gerep, I don't have an `agents` method. In the code above, its used to pull the agent associated with the provided `user_zip`. As in running `zipcode.agents` in a many-to-many association. 

@TRENT, I'll give this a shot. Seems like I'm on the right track, just having a heck of a time wrapping my head around it. haha. =)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Rails! I recently started learning Rails as well, but I think I can help: A controller action will redirect by default to a view with the same name. So after assigning the value of @user_zip, the controller will serve up agents/find.html.erb, which will have access to @user_zip. Since @user_zip is an instance of Zipcode, you'd be able to use @user_zip.agents.

Somewhat tangential, but I also suggest considering using search rather than find for the action name, only because find and its variations are used elsewhere in Rails.

Comment: Gotcha. Thanks for the help!! That clarifies things a bit for me.

Comment: I'm glad my answer was useful?